# Why does changing the positioning of a table-row element from 'static' to 'absolute' back to 'static' result in a permanent height change?

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-tables

A `display: table-row` div with `height: 75px` is nested inside a `display: table` div with `height: 100px`

The height of the child is `100px` initially with `position: static`

By changing the positioning of the child element to `absolute` and then back to `static`, the height of the child permanently changes from `100px` to `75px`.

It only occurs if the parent element is a table and the child is a table-row *and* apparently it's only in WebKit; firefox/IE change back to 100px height but Chrome/Safari don't.

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        Hello, world!
    </div>
</div>

#div1
{
    display: table;
    height: 100px;
}

#div2
{
    display: table-row;
    height: 75px;
}
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattam/t5mB3/1) with the example and output of the positioning type/height.

I originally noticed it by messing with CSS properties in the Chrome developer tools, so it's not something specific to jsfiddle or jQuery.

Why does the height permanently change?

Comment: it sets it back to 100 in the jsfiddle? Am i missing something?

Comment: It does? For me I see `static ...: 100 absolute ...: 75 static ...: 75`

Comment: Interesting! I see 100, 75, 75 in Chrome and Safari, but 100, 75, 100 in all other browsers. Probably a bug in Webkit.

Comment: :D to get it to be consistent you may need to code a script to check the heights (if this is for a project)

Comment: @MrLister Oh huh, that's interesting. I'll edit that in!

Comment: @NicholasYoung Yeah, I think I'll have to do that.

Comment: Well you are trying to specify a table-row without any table-cell. That's as if you were building this : `<table><tr>My content<tr></table>` without any `<td>`. This http://jsfiddle.net/t5mB3/3/ should give you more proper dimensions. OR by adding a table-cell and setting it's height http://jsfiddle.net/t5mB3/5/

Comment: @Niflhel: The browser will create an anonymous table cell if no explicit `display: table-cell` is found, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: When switching between `display: block` and `display: table-row`, the same thing happens. In your scenario, what probably happens is the rendering engine "resets" an element with `position: absolute` to `display: block`, because a absolutely positioned table row doesn't really make sense (and I believe that situation isn't directly defined in the CSS specs). So there most likely is a bug setting it back.

Comment: @RoToRa: It's defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: Ah, so it does do what it I believed: With `position: absolute` the element is considered to be `display: block`. More guesses: Setting the inner element to `block` leads to an "empty" table element, and anonymous (empty) elements are added to "fill it out". When its set back to `display: table-row` it's somewhere are the wrong location in the DOM and the browser gets confused. If you set `#div1` to a block and back to a table then everythign works fine.

Comment: @RoToRa: You're right - I hadn't considered the effect of anonymous table boxes on the empty table after removing the table-row. Chrome might be adding an anonymous table-row after the table-row is first removed. The problem is, [the spec never said a table couldn't be empty](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes), so (rhetorical question) why is Chrome putting in an anonymous box?

Comment: If i understand it correctly, when `#div2` becomes a block, it's wrapped with an anonymous row and cell (point 2). When it's turned back into a table-row it's obviously in the wrong location. However I can't identity any rules that would require the anonymous elements to be removed. All items of point 1 don't seem to apply (on a quick read through).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem lies in the fact that the table and table-row elements have specified heights, but the table height is greater than the table-row height. Since there are no other rows, this will result in undefined behavior. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout):

> CSS 2.1 does not define how extra space is distributed when the 'height' property causes the table to be taller than it otherwise would be.

The following is what appears to be happening, at least based on my own observations:

1. Unless I'm misreading it, every browser seems to be ignoring the paragraph in the spec that specifies how to compute the height of a table-row element, and taking the table height instead.
2. When you absolutely position the table-row, its computed height changes to the specified `75px`, because [absolute positioning turns it into a block box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) and therefore its dimensions are calculated accordingly.
3. When you return the element to its static position, it reverts to a table-row (as it should), but Chrome/Safari, for some reason, keeps the `75px` from when you made it a block box, while other browsers recalculate the height according to the table, again ignoring its specified height.

As this is technically undefined behavior, whether any of the browsers can be said to have buggy or incorrect behavior is debatable. However, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that this could be related to Chrome's tendency to mess up badly at reflows and repaints, since you'd expect a browser to revert all properties and repaint the layout correctly when you undo a single property change — something Chrome is notoriously bad at.

---

Alternatively, as mentioned in the comments, this may have something to do with [anonymous table objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes). The spec does not say that an empty table needs to have an anonymous row and cell, but it looks like Chrome could be creating one to replace the table-row when you first position it, but forgetting to remove it after you put it back in.

For example, if you add some bare text as a child of your table, which the browser will then wrap in an anonymous row box per the spec:

```
<div id="div1">
    Anonymous row
    <div id="div2">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Every browser will consistently report the height of `#div2` as `75px`.](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/t5mB3/11) Presumably, the remaining space is taken up by the anonymous row box, but unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the CSS table model to comment further.